# Send command to customer pole display COM2 using Serialport nodejs module

Tags: javascript, angular, serial-port, electron

I tried sending a clear screen command to a customer pole display, its model LCD210 its baud rate 9600, 8, n, 1(V.1), and 20 characters 2 lines display with a command type: CD5220, Font: U.S.A  /PC437. I had manual but while I am trying to send commands. It's not picking it up, it just prints like string.

Below is my code.

```
  onDisplayTextOnPole(msg: any) {

    //Check if we are in electron env
    if (this.isElectron()) {

      //Start
      const port =  new this.serialPort('COM2', { baudRate: 9600 }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log('Error: ', err.message);
        }
      });



      port.write('\0x0C');//Command to clear screen
      port.write(Buffer.from(msg), function(err: { message: any; }) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message)
        }
        console.log('message written')
      });
      port.close();
      //End 

    }


  }
```

I actually want to clear the screen first then write a message. The issue i'm having is that whenever i send a new message, it appends to the previous message. so i need a way to clear the previous message before writing the new message.

Comment: Did you resolved your problem? If so please give me a tip.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem with the code below:

```
this.myserialportinstance.write(Buffer.from('CLR', 'hex'));
```